# How to get find next one in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

its a basic question, but i dont find the doc for that...

my function : i have users with multiple bookings,
i need to get only the first booking from today for each user (the first Next meeting for user) .

so I trying to build function that gave me only the first result that he find from today but i get back the latest record from the database, what i missing?

```
   //GET NEXT MEET BY USER ID//
  exports.nextMeet = (req, res) => {
  const start = new Date();
Meeting.findOne({ startDate: { $gte: start }, determinedBy: req.profile._id })
    .populate("determinedBy", "_id name")
    .sort("-startDate")
    .exec((err, meet) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error user meeting!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: err,
            });
        }
        console.log("userLAST meet from next meet", meet);
        res.json(meet);
    });
    };
```

- user schema:

  ```
   const userSchema = new Schema({
   name: {
   type: String,
   trim: true,
   required: true,
   },
   email: {
   type: String,
   trim: true,
   required: true,
   },
   password: {
   type: String,
   },
    role: {
   type: String,
   default: "member",
   },
   resetPassword: {
   data: String,
   default: "",
  },

  created: {
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now,
  },
  salt: String,
  updated: Date,
   });
  ```
- meetings schema

  ```
    const meetingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    massageType: {
   type: String,
   enum: ["נשימות", "תאילנדי", "שוודי", "רקמות עמוק"],
   required: "Massage type is required",
   },
   startDate: {
   type: Date,
   required: "date is required",
    },
   endDate: {
   type: Date,
   required: "date is required",
   },
    determinedBy: {
   type: ObjectId,
   ref: "User",
   },
   created: {
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now(),
   },
    });
  ```

Comment: can you share the user schemas

Comment: user schema is ok. i think what u need is maybe the meetings schema,
i edit my post with the 2 schemas (meeting, and user)

Comment: have you tried it without the condition of 'determinedBy: req.profile._id ' and got the result?

Comment: i need the determined because i check it for user. each user that sign in, get the "next meet" that he was have

Comment: just for test, because I'm afraid of the problem is condition doesn't work cause of the typing of req.profile._id

Comment: ok i tried but nothing dont change..

Comment: i think that need to add something to the query, beacuse right it find the latest meeting all the time.. ok ! while im write this comment i just see that i have sort "-startDate" i removed the minus in the start, and it work.
so i see that "find one" method it find the one that correct and go out , am i right?

Comment: FindOne return One data equal the condition you set, so you right

Comment: So its like find method at "filter" array?. It find the first one end exit?